# Blazor Page Source on AuthorizeView

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am unable to see full the page source when I'm logged in and authorized using AuthorizeView

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    <p><em>@infoMessage</em></p>

    @if (listingList != null && listingList.Count > 0)
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var l in listingList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@l.Id</td>
                        <td><img src="@l.MainImage" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" width="300" height="200" /></td>
                        <td>@l.Title</td>
                        <td>@l.Description</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }

</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <h1>You're not signed in</h1>
</NotAuthorized>
```

...so I can see all my listings on the page. When I check page source in Firefox it only shows NotAuthorized section.

```
<div class="content px-4">        
    <h1>You're not signed in</h1>    
</div>
```

is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Do you have the same issue in Chrome? Can you reproduce using a minimal new project? It would make sense if you were signed out but this may need more info to diagnose.

Comment: please explain your problem. Do you mean that your page source is different from what you see?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was caused by browser caching.